# How to create this kind of Service in Android development?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have 3 activity, and all of them must synchronize user information .So I'd like to  create a kind of Service.It must be running all of the time, even before  root Activity is shown,  and until the app is closed. The 3 activity communicate to the Service and to get user information  and change user information. What kind of Service  should I use, and how to create it?

Comment: your service contains what??? if you want to store a data then you can use sharedpref od database

Comment: service basically used when you want to perform some task and your app is not on foreground

Comment: The user infomation comes from website and changed frequently.So local database is not comfortable.

Comment: you can use model i mean hold the data into variables it will be helpful as you want data till your app is alive

Comment: You are right, but the app has 3 activity, and all of them have to variables: userid, virtualmoney.So data consistency is very important.I'd like to create a customized Service, which get user information from webserver .All activity  then synchronize user data through this service.

Comment: you can save all data in model and make it singleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use a bound Service. You can use bound services to communicate with activities. Here is the link to bound services documentation: [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you need a service.
What you need is a single [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) that handle all the [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) opertaions on the data, and each on of the activity will use the same instance of the class for access the user information.

Comment: The user infomation comes from website and changed frequently.

Comment: changed frequently in the server side?

Comment: Yes, this is a virtual stock trading app.